# TYPO3 update from 4.5 to 4.7, no pages workable in backed

Tags: typo3, updates, backend

I've made a TYPO3 Update from 4.5.31 to 4.7.17.
After the normal update process, there's no problem with frontend & backend.
Update Wizard at install Tool, I can't edit my pages. There's no Content availible.
I click at my PageTree to page XY and on my right column is no content?!

The Frontend is still availible. I have an admin-account. 
Delete typo3temp files, delete caches, .. where's my problem?
My database "is ok" no error at backend, install tool or frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Uff .... problem solved.

I upload my 'typo3' and 't3lib' on the FTP Server again and now everything works fine ..